# Crystal Reports - Avoiding Cartesian Product When Grouping Three Commands

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, cartesian-product

My Crystal Report is composed of three separate SQL database commands;
- the first obtains general account info,
- the second obtains attribute A which may be one or more records,
- and the third obtains attribute B which may be one or more records.
Attributes A and B will always have at least one record and are independent of each other, only joined to the general account record.
I wish to present the data as:
GenInfo MoreGenInfo
...................................Attribute A
...................................Another Attribute A
...................................................................Attribute B
...................................................................Another Attribute B
I am using three groups in this report.

My attempts with different grouping configurations either gives me a Cartesian product or just the last attribute record (when placing fields in the Group Footer).
What's the secret sauce here?

Comment: What is your linking between these commands

Comment: The three commands are linked as inner joins to a field called Acct that is present in each query.

Answer (score 0):

You nees to use sub reports.

In main report group by gen info and now in take 2 sub reports and place in 2 group footer sections and supress group header and detail sections.

In one sub report show the data for attribute A and in second sub report show the data for attribute B.